# Elastic search range dates

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have created an Elastic search index from a Mongo database.
The documents in Mongo have the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("525facace4b0c1f5e78753ea"),
    "time" : ISODate("2013-10-17T09:23:56.131Z"),
    "type" : "A",
    "url" : "www.google.com",
    "name" : "peter",
}
```

The index was created (apparently) without any problems.
Now, I am trying to use Elastic Search to retrieve the documents in the index between two dates. I have read that I have to use range queries, but I have tried many times things like

```
MatchQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "peter").type(Type.PHRASE).minimumShouldMatch("99%");
LocalDateTime toLocal = new LocalDateTime(2013,12,18, 0, 0);
Date to = toLocal.toDate();
LocalDateTime fromLocal = new LocalDateTime(2013,12,17, 0, 0);
Date from = fromLocal.toDate();
RangeQueryBuilder queryDate = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("time").to(to).from(from);
FilterBuilder filterDate = FilterBuilders.queryFilter(queryDate);       

srb = esH.client.prepareSearch("my_index");
srb.setQuery(queryBuilder);
srb.setFilter(filterDate);
sr = srb.execute().actionGet();
```

and I get 0 hits although there should be many results. I have tried to enter strings instead of dates, but same results.

When I perform a basic query without filters such as:

```
MatchQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "peter").type(Type.PHRASE).minimumShouldMatch("99%");

SearchRequestBuilder srb = esH.client.prepareSearch("my_index");
rb.setQuery(queryBuilder);
SearchResponse sr = srb.execute().actionGet();
```

I get hits with that look like this:

```
{
"_index" : "my_index",
"_type" : "type",
"_id" : "5280d3c2e4b05e95aa703e34",
"_score" : 1.375688, "_source" : {"type":["A"],"time":["Mon Nov 11 13:55:30 CET 2013"],"name":["peter"]}
}
```

Where the field `time` does not have the format `ISODate("2013-10-17T09:23:56.131Z")`anymore.

To sum up, what would be the Java code (and types) for querying between two dates (and times), taking into account the format?

Comment: Could you add the actual JSON query that the builder is generating? It's really hard to say what's happening without seeing what ES is actually seeing.

Answer (score 10):

You are probably passing the wrong field name to the range query at this line:

```
RangeQueryBuilder queryDate = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("time").to(to).from(from);
```

It should probably be `@timestamp` (or the field you're using to store your timestamp) instead of `time`. Additionally, it seems that there is no `time` field in Elasticsearch for the example document you included. This also points to the issue that the `time` field wasn't converted correctly from Mongo to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try

```
FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("@timestamp").from("from time").to("toTime")
```

Comment: Is this deprecated or something? Cause it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

This will work -

You can pass in Long timestamps to the gte and lte params.

QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("time").gte(startTime).lte(endTime);

Make sure to add an "L" at the end of the startTime and endTime, so that it knows its a long and not an int.